# my computer fan shorted out

Tags: boot, display, fan

I just built a new pc yesturday and I powered it up and it worked fine for about 3 hours then I was moving the fans around inside and two wires from the led fans sparked and now my computer wont turn. I tryed taking out the fan and it still wont turn on. What I mean by not turning on is basicly when I hit the on button it turns on but no screen pops up no sounds no boot no nothing please help.

Comment: Oops, two wires sparked? I think your Computer is dead. You may start searching for the broken component - but most likely it is the motherboard and even some other parts...

Answer (score 0):

As FiveO said, try starting you PC with minimum amount of hardware. Meaning: Mainboard, RAM and CPU. Let away the GPU and other components and see if it starts.

Is the PSU Fan spinning?

What kind of fan do you use that moving it around causes sparks? werent the wires isolated?